# A word for a light thud that a letter makes when dropped into the wooden mailbox

Tags: vocabulary, onomatopoeia

What is the word for a light thud that a letter makes when dropped into a wooden mailbox?

Comment: What's wrong with "light thud"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found these results after doing a Google search on `"envelope landed with a"`:

- thud (7)
- soft thud (5)
- dull thud (3)
- thump (1)
- soft thump (1)
- schlap (1)
- thwack (1)
- clunk (1)
- clink (1)
- tap (1)

The ones I think are most appropriate for a wooden mailbox would be:

- *thud, thump, tap, thwack*

Other candidate words might include:

- *knock, rap, tick*

and here are some adjectives you might consider:

- *muffled, quiet, quick, soft, dull, muted, faint*

leading to several possible combinations, such as:

- *soft tick, muffled tap, dull knock, faint thwack, quiet rap, quick thump, muted thud*

Answer (score -1):

Depends, I suppose, on what the mailbox is made of, what it's attached to, and how tightly coupled the two are.

Candidates that leap to mind include:

tok
thock
thunk
chink
ktang
thwock

Comment: These are not words in wide currency. I forgot to say this but it is made of wood, the mailbox.

Comment: Of these "thunk" has the widest currency, though it might not be light enough for your purpose.

Comment: A native speaker in this circumstance (not having exactly the right pre-existing word for a sound) will in fact invent an onomatopoeia, btw.  This is one small way that English got into the general mess it's in.

Comment: The onomatopoeia could be 'dub' the second sound of the heartbeat.

Comment: @Codeswitcher How about *plop*? It might relate to water, but I think it could apply to the sound something light dropped on a surface as well.